# returns an ArrayList using a while loop and an iterator

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have a big problem with the following method.

```
public class PoliceDepartment{
    private ArrayList<PoliceOfficer> policeOfficers;


    public PoliceDepartment()
    {
        policeOfficers = new ArrayList<PoliceOfficer>();
    }

    public void addPoliceOfficers(PoliceOfficer newPoliceOfficers)
    {
    if(newPoliceOfficers != null)
    {
        policeOfficers.add(newPoliceOfficers);
    }
    }
```

A method that accepts an officer name as a parameter, validates that the passed parameter is not     null, searches the collection and returns an ArrayList of the parking tickets issued by that officer or returns null if there were no parking tickets issued by the specified officer. The officer name is case-insensitive. This method uses a while loop and an iterator to implement the required functionality.

```
public ArrayList<ParkingTicket> getAllTicketByOfficer(String officerName) {
    ArrayList<PoliceOfficer> al = new ArrayList<PoliceOfficer>();
    Iterator<PoliceOfficer> it = policeOfficers.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        PoliceOfficer officer = it.next();
        if(officerName != null && officerName.equalsIgnoreCase(officer.getOfficerName())){  
            al.add(officer);
        }
        else {
            return null; 
        }
    }
    return al;
 }
```

I have a problem with the line:

```
 return al;
```

The error found says "Incompatible type")

I don't understand how to do it. Could someone help me?

Comment: You're iterating over an **empty** `ArrayList`. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Post the code where you put objects into the ArrayList.

Comment: Worse, you're iterating over the list you want to modify.

Comment: You're attempting to iterate `parkingTickets`; a `List` created at the beginning of your method. It's empty. You might try to iterate `policeOfficers`.

Comment: You added code where you _can_ add objects, but as others have pointed out, that's not the ArrayList that you are iterating over.

Comment: @user3040075 Since your edit, the method says it should return an `ArrayList<ParkingTicket>` but you are returning `al` which is an `ArrayList<PoliceOfficer>`. Depending on what you need you either change the return type of the method or change the object you actually return. It looks like it should be the latter. You are making a list of officers when what you need is a list of the tickets they wrote.

Answer (score -1):

You're adding PoliceOfficers to a list of ParkingTickets. The types are incompatible.

Comment: `PoliceOfficer` does not appear anywhere in the method in question.

Comment: The user is talking about the method at the bottom, but has now edited the question so my answer is no longer relevant.